# Pygame and spin box

Tags: pygame

I need to create a spin box, but I just don't have idea about how to start!. I´ve been looking for some information, but I just couldn't find anything, I would apreciate any help!
Thanks!

PD: This is realy important

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a class called `spinBox`. This class consist of

- **one [class attribute](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) called `font`** which holds an PyGame font object.
- **four methods**:

  - `.draw()`: draws the `spinBox` onto the passed surface
  - `.increment()`, `.decrement()`: increments or decrements the current state of the Spinbox
  - `.__call__()`: handles click event

  as well as

  - the `__init__()` method.
- and **fife instance attributes**:

  - `self.rect`
  - `self.image`
  - `self.buttonRects`
  - `self.state`
  - `self.step`

The `spinBox` class:

```
class spinBox:
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)

    def __init__(self, position):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(position, (85, 60))
        self.image = pygame.Surface(self.rect.size)
        self.image.fill((55,155,255))

        self.buttonRects = [pygame.Rect(50,5,30,20),
                             pygame.Rect(50,35,30,20)]

        self.state = 0
        self.step = 1

    def draw(self, surface):
        #Draw SpinBox onto surface
        textline = spinBox.font.render(str(self.state), True, (255,255,255))

        self.image.fill((55,155,255))

        #increment button
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, (255,255,255), self.buttonRects[0])
        pygame.draw.polygon(self.image, (55,155,255), [(55,20), (65,8), (75,20)])
        #decrement button
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, (255,255,255), self.buttonRects[1])
        pygame.draw.polygon(self.image, (55,155,255), [(55,40), (65,52), (75,40)])

        self.image.blit(textline, (5, (self.rect.height - textline.get_height()) // 2))

        surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def increment(self):
        self.state += self.step

    def decrement(self):
        self.state -= self.step

    def __call__(self, position):
        #enumerate through all button rects
        for idx, btnR in enumerate(self.buttonRects):
            #create a new pygame rect with absolute screen position
            btnRect = pygame.Rect((btnR.topleft[0] + self.rect.topleft[0],
                                   btnR.topleft[1] + self.rect.topleft[1]), btnR.size)

            if btnRect.collidepoint(position):
                if idx == 0:
                    self.increment()
                else:
                    self.decrement()
```

Example usage:

```
#import pygame and init modules
import pygame
pygame.init()

#create pygame screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,300))
screen.fill((255,255,255))

#create new spinBox instance called *spinBox1*
spinBox1 = spinBox((20, 50))
spinBox1 .draw(screen)

pygame.display.flip()

while True:
    #wait for single event
    ev = pygame.event.wait()

    #call spinBox1 if pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN event detected
    if ev.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and ev.button == 1:
        spinBox1(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
        spinBox1.draw(screen)

        #updtae screen
        pygame.display.flip()

    if ev.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and ev.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
        pygame.quit()
        exit()
```

Please note that this is **only an example code**. Anyway, I hope I could help you a little bit :)

Comment: @Shape: No problem, I'm glad I could help you! :) If you want you could accept this answer (click on the green tick mark beside an answer). If you have any problems in the future let us know. :D

Comment: This example is fantastic. Thanks! Could you give me a hint on how to enable the user to type in a value in the spin box?